# Make Whonix Gateway exit from VPN? Web proxy recommendations?

Tags: configuration, whonix, vpn, web-proxy

Is there a way to mess with the Whonix Gateway VM so that I can have a VPN be the final exit point for Workstation data before reaching destination servers? This would be great as it would help me avoid being blocked from sites that don't play nice with Tor, without having to use a VPS/cloud machine or web proxy just have the ability to do banking or voip over Whonix.

If this isn't advisable for me to attempt or there isn't any guide, do you know of any good web proxy or that I could use on it instead for banking, a quality premium one which accepts bitcoin?

Comment: It's possible. Although common way to do this would be installing the VM inside the Workstation so it becomes the last hop. Do you know the related documentation https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Features#VPN_.2F_Tunnel_support already?

Comment: Looking closer at the site (thanks for the links!), I realize that I can just/must use a VPN in Whonix, via OpenVPN on the Workstation and not the Gateway, to achieve this and also get around the UDP issue. But when I try to install open vpn with "sudo apt-get update && apt-get install openvpn" I get "E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)" and "E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?" Any thoughts on how to get around this? This is why I wish it had a better set of GUI options! I wish they'd used Mint as the basis!

Comment: Actually I just found the answer to that here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/423143/solving-var-lib-dpkg-lock-open-13-permission-denied-with-are-you-root-e

Comment: @adrelanos The problem with that last issue that "sudo" was not in the second part of the command. I thought I had another issue with OpenVPN, but resolved upon realizing it doesn't have its own standalone app but serves as a backbone for KDE Network Connection on Whonix. I'm pretty much set with that I guess. Thanks for your help and initially referring me to their literature. It is a lot to take in but I think my setup has come together.